Nodemailder node js email
Hello I'm having problems with this Node js code running in VS Code which is meant to send emails and I need help.
I got the code from the Nodemailer website and modified for my own variables and app key not shown in this code.
When I run the code with debugging it worked and I recieved an email also in the console in VS code it says "Message sent".
(Note: Sometimes when I run without debugging the email does not get sent and the in the console it shows no error instead VS Code show play forever. It seems like the code just keeps on running)
I inserted this working function (sendMail) to call it from my Main program (AI Chatbot) Script.js but it hangs my Main program and seems like it keeps running.
//---Rayn Copied code working standlone with debug//

console.log('Rayn start');

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: "abc@gmail.com",
    pass: "bucb qxpq XXXX XXXX",
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'abc@gmail.com',
  to: 'xyz@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Nice Nodemailer test 1,
  text: 'Hey there, its our first message sent with Nodemailer ',
  html: '<b>Hey there! </b><br> This is our first message sent with Nodemailer<br /><img src="cid:uniq-mailtrap.png" alt="mailtrap" />',
  };

transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  }
  console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <d786aa62-4e0a-070a-47ed-0b0666549519@xxx.xxxxx>

});

  // process.exit(0); //
  // process.on('exit', function() { process.exit(0); }); //


//----Rayn end of Copied code working standlone with debug//








===================== Main AI Chatbot  Script.js

window.onload = function() {


  let liveChat = false;
  document.querySelector("#chat-bot-close").onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector("#open-form").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#closed-form").style.display = "block";
  };

  document.querySelector("#closed-form").onclick = function(){
    this.style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#open-form").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("#chat-bot-drop-down-content").style.display = "none";
    if (! document.querySelector("#chat-bot-text").style.display == "block") {
      document.querySelector("#chat-bot-form").style.display = "block"
    }
  };


//Submit button after entering Name and Email on chat form //

  document.querySelector("#start-chat-submit button[type='submit']").onclick = function(){
    const form = document.forms["start-chat-submit"];
    const name = form.elements[0].value;
    const email = form.elements[1].value;
    if (name != "" && email != "") {
      sendUserInfo(name, email)


//
// Inserted into window.onload
//
//---Rayn Copied code working standlone with debug//


console.log('Rayn start');

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: "abc@gmail.com",
    pass: "bucb qxpq XXXX XXXX",
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'abc@gmail.com',
  to: 'xyz@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Nice Nodemailer test 1,
  text: 'Hey there, its our first message sent with Nodemailer ',
  html: '<b>Hey there! </b><br> This is our first message sent with Nodemailer<br /><img src="cid:uniq-mailtrap.png" alt="mailtrap" />',
  };

transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  }
  console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <d786aa62-4e0a-070a-47ed-0b0666549519@xxx.xxxxx>

});

  // process.exit(0); //
  // process.on('exit', function() { process.exit(0); }); //


//----Rayn end of Copied code working standlone with debug//
// End insertion


      document.querySelector("#chat-bot-form").remove();
      document.querySelector("#chat-bot-text").style.display = "block"
      if (document.querySelector("#chat-bot-drop-down-content p") != null) {
        document.querySelector("#chat-bot-drop-down-content p").remove()
      }
      setCookie("name", name, 10);
    } else if (document.querySelector("#start-chat-submit p") == null) {
      const errorMessage = document.createElement("p");
      errorMessage.textContent = "Please submit a valid name and email";
      errorMessage.style.color = "red";
      form.replaceChild(errorMessage, form.childNodes[7]);
    };
  };

//================================= END


